# Material Design - one search field, two available actions

Tags: material-design, material-ui

Need a tip for design. Now we have a one search field, with 2 actions - where you  can search for a role or a user

1. If you search for a user you can copy his (role) assignments OR
2. If you search for a role you can add the selected role.

Generally, UI looks now like this:

[Copy user's assignments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOEyh.png)

[Add role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV3TD.png)

How can this UI be simplified for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a menu to the Appbar, similar to the *Menus* section of the Material Design standard for [Layout Structure](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar):

[image]
[image]

The images above are pulled from [the standard](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar), but could be used in your case.

Ditch the radio buttons and present the current search context with its default placeholder text in the search field.  Offer a button in the Appbar that presents a modal Menu.

When the menu is presented, offer the available search contexts to the user, allowing them to switch.  Upon selection, re-render the search field with new placeholder text.  It should probably clear anything that was previously entered.

If for some reason the set of contexts is limited to one (permissions, security, or another reason), present that option in the placeholder text and hide the menu button.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip! I really appreciate and definitely use your suggestion!

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I believe that this is not an option... This looks, I  think, no better..? https://pasteboard.co/HbSvAfZ.png

Comment: By "Offer a button in the Appbar that presents a modal Menu." I meant that the button should be in the Appbar (as it is in the attached images)